# Android AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can I use await for async class in android like used in C# ,

```
        int stocktakingId = 0;

        if (Stocktaking.SynchCountId == 0) {

            stocktakingId = NewStocktaking(Stocktaking, UHFApplication.getInstance().getData("UserID"), _stocktakingType);

            Stocktaking.setSynchCountId(stocktakingId);

          );

        } else {
            stocktakingId = Stocktaking.getSynchCountId();
        }
```

I want to await **NewStocktakin** metod. This callback method. after return NewStocktakin  value I must continue below line. its possible ? Because my **stocktakingId** is return 0.

```
 public int NewStocktaking(Stocktaking stocktaking, String userId, Constants.StocktakingType stocktakingType) {

    new NewStocktakingService(count -> count).
            execute(
                    String.valueOf(stocktaking.getName()),
                    String.valueOf(stocktaking.getRelatedId()),
                    String.valueOf(userId),
                    String.valueOf(stocktakingType)
            );

    return 0;
}
```

and also inteface metod

```
 public interface AsyncResponseNewStocktaking {
    int processFinish(int count);
 }
```

and my async class

```
 public class NewStocktakingService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ResponseModel> {

    AsyncResponseNewStocktaking delegate = null;

    NewStocktakingService(AsyncResponseNewStocktaking delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseModel doInBackground(String... parameters) {

        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
        ResponseModel responseModel = requestHandler.getRequestGet(UHFApplication.getInstance().apiUrl + "/api/MobileService/NewStocktaking?" +
                "stocktakingName=" + URLEncoder.encode(parameters[0]) +
                "&relatedID=" + parameters[1] +
                "&userID=" + parameters[2] +
                "&stocktakingType=" + parameters[3]);
        return responseModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ResponseModel responseModel) {

        super.onPostExecute(responseModel);

        if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == responseModel.httpStatus) {

            int count = Integer.parseInt(responseModel.responseString);

            delegate.processFinish(count);

        } else {
            delegate.processFinish(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the value of Your `AsyncTask` class. You can await using the `.get()` method.

So your final code should be like:

```
 public int NewStocktaking(Stocktaking stocktaking, String userId, Constants.StocktakingType stocktakingType) {

  return  new NewStocktakingService(count -> count).
            execute(
                    String.valueOf(stocktaking.getName()),
                    String.valueOf(stocktaking.getRelatedId()),
                    String.valueOf(userId),
                    String.valueOf(stocktakingType)
            ).get();
}
```

But that will require you to make your AsynTask return `Integer`. Checking your code, you anyways dont use the other properties of the `ResponeModel` so you can make `onBackground()` return Integer!

Comment: O may Good, Thanks so much :)